# How to delete all the data from a database?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Just Data. The size of the database in the status tab should be `0 MB`.
Is there any API that can do the work and what if I try to purge all the directories using unix commands. Is it recommended ?

Answer (score 5):

The Admin UI approach mentioned by Kishan will use forest-clear functionality, which you can invoke programmatically as well. That will be done almost instantly, where the document-delete approach would not scale well on large databases.

Try using the [xdmp:forest-clear()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-clear) method like this:

```
for $forest-id in xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database())
return xdmp:forest-clear($forest-id)
```

Note: I would strongly recommend against tampering with MarkLogic data files from file-system, unless guided by MarkLogic Support, or a MarkLogic Expert.

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

From the admin console, go to the particular database `configure` page. You can see the clear option. Clear will delete all the data in the database.

Alternatively,
You can use the following query:

`xdmp:document-delete(cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query(())))`.

`cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query(()))` will match all the documents in the database and `xdmp:document-delete()` will delete those documents.